# Angular 2 - unable to recognize node_modules on index.html

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have been trying to get a grasp of angular 2 and created an app (without angular cli) which worked just fine. Now after reading though many blogs and tutorials understood that angular-cli is the recommended way of creating angular 2 apps and I did just that but the same app complains about not finding node_modules folder and any libraries within it.

Any help would be appreciated on this.
If you need additional artifacts let me know and I will add.

(Updated with package.json)

```
{
  "name": "angular2-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "primeng": "^1.1.1",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.45",
    "devextreme" : "16.2.3",
    "devextreme-angular" : "16.2.3-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to know what commands you ran. Installing Angular CLI via npm, and then just doing "ng new myprojectname", then running "ng serve" has worked flawlessly for me many times. Literally just follow the commands on the angular CLI home page to get up and running.

Comment: For the record, the CLI makes it easy but after a while you see you really don't need it. It's handy for bootstrapping and ideal if you're into TS, but plain ol' ES6/Babel/Webpack works fine, I wrote a bit on it and have a seed project on github, go to www.tcoz.com and look in "Errata" for the Angular 2, Webpack and Babel article.

Comment: I did ran ng new <projectname> to create the project and running ng serve does brings up the app but throws 404 for any node_mdoules entries

Comment: Maybe your version of NPM, something is going wrong with the install?

Comment: the node_modules are getting installed just fine as I could see the libraries, just a thought is it required to be added in angular-cli.json instead of html?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything at all. I tried it a couple of times and it seems to work absolutely fine. 
It'd be interesting to see your config files. Here for example is the package.json file that I posted in another question that helped somebody out. Does it seem to match? If so, maybe we could compare the angular-cli config files. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271008/angular2-build-error-ts2305/41271262#41271262

Comment: apologies for the late response, had been in a training. Updated the package.json. Do you know if the angular-cli.json needs to be updated for getting that working? There are some properties in there which I cannot make any sense of and neither can I find any good documentation around it. Do you have any insight into it?

Comment: Yes I know my way around the file fairly well, and you're right, docs on it are sparse to say the least. The idea is you're never supposed to touch it really other than maybe adding external scripts, but of course that never really pans out. If you have any specific questions on it let me know.

Comment: Did you see any discrepancies in the package.json file? 
Regarding the angular-cli.json file, what is the use for addons and packages properties?

Comment: Take a look at this file. It has brief descriptions of the angular-cli.json schema: https://github.com/tcoz/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular-cli/lib/config/schema.json. I also looked through the rest of the repo for a few mins. "Packages", I couldn't really find used anywhere, but I'm assuming it is a way to add an external package that you may not be able to install directly into the project. AddOns is used pretty extensively though, angular-cli loads quite a few, and they appear to be a way to extend the CLI itself with more commands and such.